# How can I make this button change the background color after selecting color from the input?

Tags: javascript

How can I make this button change the background color after selecting color from the input??

```js
var theInput = document.getElementById("favColor");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var theColor = theInput.value;

theInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  body.style.background = theInput.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="color" name="colorChange" value="" id="favColor">
    <button id="changeColor">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Right now you're attaching an event listener to the `"change"` event of your color picker. Change the event to be on the `"click"` event of the *button* instead. Additionally, put the attribute `type="button"` on your `<button>`. Most browsers will default to `type="submit"`, which will submit your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach a click event to the button `changeColor` then perform the color change inside this event, like :

```
  var button = document.querySelector("#changeColor");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    body.style.background = theInput.value;
  }, false);
```

**NOTE :** A button inside `form` is by default a submit button, so you should add `type='button'` :

```
<button id="changeColor" type="button">Click me</button>
```

Or `e.preventDefault()` :

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    body.style.background = theInput.value;
}, false);
```

To prevent the form submit and page refresh after the click.

Hope this helps.

**Working snippet :**

```js
var theInput = document.getElementById("favColor");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var button = document.querySelector("#changeColor");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.background = theInput.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="color" name="colorChange" value="" id="favColor">
  <button id="changeColor" type="button">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color of the button to change as soon as the user types the color in, change the event listener from `change` to `keyUp` like such:

```html
<form>
  <input type="color" name="colorChange" value="" id="favColor">
  <button id="changeColor">Click me</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var theInput = document.getElementById("favColor");
  var body = document.querySelector("body");
  var theColor = theInput.value;


  theInput.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
   document.getElementById("changeColor").style.background = theInput.value;
  }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var theInput = document.getElementById("favColor");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var theColor = theInput.value;

function changeColor() {
  body.style.background = theInput.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="colorChange" value="" id="favColor">
<button id="changeColor" onclick="changeColor()">Click me</button>
```